# ¿Cómo validar si espacio de un array int no tiene valor?

Tags: java, array, método

soy nuevo y tengo una duda en java respecto a que hacer para verificar si un espacio de un array de enteros no tiene un valor asignado.
Lo que quiero hacer es un método que reciba un array int y devuelva el mismo pero sin los posibles espacios sin ocupar del arreglo que entró como parámetro, retornando así sólo los números en el arreglo parámetro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un arreglo en java se rellena automáticamente con el valor por defecto del tipo de variable.

En el caso de una arreglo de int, este al inicializarse, se rellena con zeros.

```
//En los dos ejemplos citados a continuación, el arreglo se rellena con 0. 
int [] array = new int[5];
int [] array = {0,0,0,0,0};
```

Para resolver tu problema, deberías hacer un bucle como el siguiente:

```
private int [] limpiarZeros(int [] arregloDeNumeros){
    int[] arregloLimpio = new int[arregloDeNumeros.length];

    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < arregloDeNumeros.length; i++){
        if(arregloDeNumeros[i] != 0) {
            arregloLimpio[j++] = arregloDeNumeros[i];
        }
    }

    return arregloLimpio;
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero mi duda es: ¿y si un número guardado por el usuario en el arreglo parámetro es 0? Y debe mandarlo en el arreglo de retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes utilizar las clases Wrapper de java (Integer en lugar de int). luego puedes utilizar programación funcional de java 8:

```
public List<Integer> obtenerArraysSinNulos(List<Integer> arrayVerificacion){
      List<Integer> arraySinNulos = new ArrayList<>();
      arrayVerificacion.stream().filter( e -> e!=null).forEach(arraySinNulos::add);
      return arraySinNulos;
   }
```

Este método te devolverá la lista del array sin valores nulos.

Espero que te sirva

Comment: gracias por tu apoyo, sin embargo el OP no muestra intento alguno y la idea en esta comunidad es que por mas minimo que sea el avance de un trabajo se coloque y sobre ese se ayude, por que tu respuesta por ejemplo le propone Java 8  y no sabes por que el no lo puso si esta en condiciones de usarlo

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por la sugerencia. Preferí darle esta respuesta porque desde mi punto de vista sería lo mas acorde al problema.